# dx-file-uploader how to upload file multi time with use button mode

Tags: angular, typescript, devexpress, devextreme

i have used dx-file-uploader in useButton mode I want to when user upload a file and send it to server could upload and send a another file to server with click on chose file and upload button actually if user want to change the file can do it by upload new file and click on send after uploading previous file

i have used dx-file-uploader in useButton mode i want to when user upload a file and send it to server could upload and send a another file to server with click on chose file and upload button actually if user want to change the file can do it by upload new file and click on send after uploading previous file
but now when we upload a file and click on send button every thing is ok but when we want to upload another file (for example to edit previous file) the send button dose not work for the second time and more… user have to close component and open it again and chose file and click on send again…

how can we use (useButton mode) - to send files multi time with uploading and click on send button

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.